# ¿Cómo convertir un objeto de una clase creada a objeto de Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

Tal como dice el título:

tengo la siguiente clase:

```
export class Producto{
  nombre: string;
  cantidad: number;
  precio: number;
  constructor(){
    //...
  }
}
```

y quiero pasar un Array de los objectos de esta misma clase:

```
[Producto, Producto, Producto, Producto]
```

a un Array de objetos de Javascript:

```
[
  {
    nombre:"azucar",
    cantidad: 5,
    precio: 2.90
  },
  {
    nombre:"pan",
    cantidad: 2,
    precio: 0.90
  },
  {},
  ....
]
```

**¿Existe algún método o función que me ayude a hacerlo?**

Me basta con solo convertir un solo objeto. Obviamente si se puede con uno entonces es cuestión de iterar con los demás. Pero mejor si existe algún método para todo...

Se agradece muchísimo la ayuda...

Comment: ¿Quieres convertir  un objeto en otro exactamente igual pero sin sus métodos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con los métodos [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) y [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) deberías poder lograr lo que quieres:

```
const objetos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productos));
```

Primero se transforma el array de elementos de tipo "Producto" a un string en formato JSON, y después se convierte a un array de nuevo de elementos tipo "Object".

Comment: como se haria eso a la inversa de json a objetos tipo producto?

Answer (score 3):

el array de objetos lo podes iterar de varias maneras pero para tu caso yo suelo utilizar forEach

```
let array=[];
[Producto, Producto, Producto, Producto].forEach(producto=>{
 array.push({ ...producto});
})
```

Comment: Que tal Hanz, bienvenido... Me alegra que partícipes con respuestas, pero el problema está en que no es eso lo que se pregunta, el problema no está en la iteración, sino en la "conversión"...  Las respuestas como esta suelen ser sujetas a puntuaciones negativas, aun así se agradece mucho la intención... Ve a [answer] para más información... De paso puedes hacer el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y así ganes tu primera medalla. Suerte!!!

Comment: gracias, creo que no entendí muy bien la cuestión pero ya esta editada :)

Answer (score 2):

Otra posible solucion seria usando [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign):

```js
let plainProducts = productos.map(
  product => Object.assign({}, product)
);
```